# Postgres ECONNREFUSED on Docker Compose with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker-compose

I get an ECONNREFUSED when trying to connect to a postgres server in docker from a NodeJS app in docker when running both via docker-compose. However I can connect from my host machine. Here is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "2.4"

services:
  api:
    build: 
      context: .
      target: dev
    depends_on: 
      - postgres
    ports: 
      - "8080:8080"
      - "9229:9229"
    networks:
      - backend
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - PGHOST=postgres
      - PGPASSWORD=12345678
      - PGUSER=test
      - PGDATABASE=test
      - PGPORT=5433
    volumes: 
      - .:/node/app
      - /node/app/node_modules # Use empty volume to hide the node_modules from the host os

  postgres:
    image: postgres:11
    restart: always
    ports:
    - "5433:5432"
    networks:
      - backend
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment: 
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 12345678
      POSTGRES_USER: test
      POSTGRES_DB: test

networks:
  backend:

volumes:
    db-data:
```

The nodeJS code:

```
const client = new Client({
      user: process.env.PGUSER,
      host: process.env.PGHOST,
      database: process.env.PGDATABASE,
      password: process.env.PGPASSWORD,
      port: Number(process.env.PGPORT),
    });
client.connect();
```

The error:

```
{ Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.22.0.2:5433
api_1   |     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1106:14)
api_1   |   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
api_1   |   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
api_1   |   syscall: 'connect',
api_1   |   address: '172.22.0.2',
api_1   |   port: 5433 }
```

At the same time I can connect from the host OS to the database server without any problems. Is there any problems with networking?

Edit: The dB server is ready to accept connections before the nodejs app tries that (I also tried with retrying the connection from within the nodejs app).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is nothing wrong with networking. Just because you're connecting on the wrong port.

Inside compose network, your `postgres` container exposed `5432` port so it only accept the request via that port inside the compose network. So just need to change `PGPORT=5433` to `PGPORT=5432`.

The reason why you can access from your host OS is because docker-compose mapped your port `5433:5432` so all request to `5433` from outside (host OS) will be pass to `5432` inside your compose network.

Hope that clear enough for you to solve the issue.